# CakePHP browser cache

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0, browser-cache

I'm having a question about browser chaching. 
I have on my website login/logout button. Problem is when I login I have to reload page to see logout button. I have this button in my layout in condition `if($logged_in)`.

I solved it by disabling all browser cache:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->disableCache();
}
```

I'm finding it like a bad solution so I want to ask for any idea. For example how to disable caching just for that one button if its possible?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
in UserController

```
    public function login() {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Spatne heslo');
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Its included in default.ctp:

```
<?php if(!$logged_in){ ?>
    <div class="login">
         <?php echo $this->Html->link('Login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));  ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($logged_in){ ?>
    <div class="logout">
       <?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you add the code related to the login part?

Comment: Of course. I added functions from controller.

Comment: can you also include the view? It's not clear how the button is not included

Comment: I'm having it in my layout default.ctp

Comment: how/where is $logged_in set?  That's pretty much the most important part, and I don't see it.

Comment: I set it in AppConroller in beforeFilter like this: $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedin());

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this yet... i just read it on cakephp documentation..

To indicate blocks of content that are not to be cached, wrap them in
'

```
  <!--nocache-->
  <!--/nocache-->
```